# How to add methods to the Enumerable module?

Tags: ruby, module, enumerable

How do I add my custom methods onto the existing Enumerable module in Ruby? I'm running Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, you can use `monkey-patching`, which incorporates the concept of `open classes`. This means that classes in Ruby can be modified at any time. For example, you could create a double method in the number class.

```
class Integer < Numeric
  def self.double
    self * 2
  end
end
```

Now you could call a double method on a number

```
4.double
=> 8
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, but where should I write that piece of code, in what file? Tnx Tom

Comment: But when I try to run it through irb I get "NoMethodError: undefined method `my_each'". Do I have to require something or tell it where to look? Tnx Tom

Comment: I found my mistake, forgot to include the file :), tnx guys for your help!

Comment: Tomisslav, you said you want to add a method to the `Enumerable` module. This answer adds one to the `Integer` class, leaving me perplexed. I've downvoted it because it does not address your question. Why did you accept it? Have I somehow misunderstood the question? (I would have directed my comment to the author of this answer but it appears he/she is no longer a member of SO.)

Answer (score 3):

The same way you add methods to every other module.

If you want to add method `bar` with parameters `baz` and `quux` to module `Foo` you write

```
module Foo
  def bar(baz, quux)
    # code code code
  end
end
```

So, if you want to add method `histogram` to module `Enumerable` you write

```
module Enumerable
  # Counts the number of occurrences of each unique object in `self`.
  #
  # @return [Hash<E, Integer>] a `Hash` of objects mapped to number of occurrences in `self`.
  def histogram
    group_by(&:itself).map {|k, v| [k, v.size] }.to_hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Jörg, I entered the method in the enumerable module just like you wrote, but i still get the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `my_each'"." So what am I doing wrong? Tnx Tom

Answer (score 1):

All methods defined in the `Enumerable` module require receivers to be either enumerators or have a method `each`. Let's suppose we wish to create an enumerable method `my_to_a` similar to [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) except it returns just the first `n` of the receiver's elements (or, if it's an enumerator, the first `n` elements it  generates), `n` being `my_to_a`'s argument.

```
module Enumerable
  def my_to_a(n)
    enum = is_a?(Enumerator) ? self : each
    n.times.with_object([]) { |o,a| a << enum.next }
   end
end

[0,1,2,3,4].my_to_a(3)
  #=> [0, 1, 2] 
(0..4).my_to_a(3)
  #=> [0, 1, 2] 
{ a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 }.my_to_a(3)
  #=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]] 
'0ab_1ab_2ab_3ab_4ab'.gsub(/.(?=ab)/).my_to_a(3)
  #=> ["0", "1", "2"] 
require 'prime'; Prime.my_to_a(4)
  #=> [2, 3, 5, 7] 
[0,1,2,3,4].my_to_a(6)
  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
'0ab_1ab_2ab_3ab_4ab'.gsub(/.(?=ab)/).my_to_a(6)
  #=> StopIteration (iteration reached an end)
```

The line

```
enum = is_a?(Enumerator) ? self : each
```

sets `enum` to `self` if `self` is an enumerator and to the enumerator `self.each` otherwise. The latter case assumes `self` has a method `each`, meaning that the class `self.class` has an instance method `each` (or a method `each` has been defined on `self`'s singleton class). `each` must return an enumerator. In the example, `is_a?(Enumerator)` (equivalent to `self.is_a?(Enumerator)`) is `true` only for the two examples that employ [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) with one argument and no block.<sup>1</sup> In the other examples `self.class.included_modules.includes?(Enumerable) #=> true` and `self.class.instance_methods.include?(:each) #=> true`. Those classes are `Array`, `Range`, `Hash` and `Prime`. `each` is an instance method for the first three, a class method for `Prime`.

Once we have the enumerator `enum` the line

```
n.times.with_object([]) { |o,a| a << enum.next }
```

is straightforward. See [Integer#times](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-times), [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) and [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

<sup>1 Note that `Enumerator.included_modules #=> [Enumerable, Kernel]`, so any method that returns an enumerator (instance of `Enumerator`) responds to `Enumerable` methods. That is, there is no need for the method's class (such as [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html)) to include `Enumerable` or have an method `each`.</sup>